# Is Await.ready really blocking main thread?

Tags: scala, future

I have a piece of code in Scala in which I use `Await.ready` in the main block and then use the corresponding value.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import concurrent.Promise

val a = Future[Int] {
  Thread.sleep(100)
  4+6
}

val b = Future[Int] {
  12
}
val r1= Await.ready(a,Duration.Inf)
val r2=Await.ready(b,Duration.Inf)
println("a = " + a)
println("b = " + b)
val k = b.flatMap(x => {a.map(y => x+y)})
println("k = " + k)
```

This results in

```
a = Future(Success(10))
b = Future(Success(12))
k = Future(<not completed>)
```

Why is `k` not computed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val k = b.flatMap(x => {a.map(y => x+y)})  
println("k = " + k)
```

`k` is a Future that will be computed in the background. The result will not be available in the very next line.

In your case, you already waited for `b` and `a` to complete, so the computation of `k` will not really take any amount of time, but some background executor will still need to evaluate the `flatMap`.

So you will need to `Await.result(k)` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the reason for _k_ being not-completed has something to do with _a_.